# TouchWiz Crash after install

Tags: android, samsung-touchwiz

My application(min api level 15) makes TouchWiz homescreen crash (testing on api level 22 android sm-j200f). I think it is because of my drawable resources and dp's but I don't know how to solve it. Any help?

Comment: How can we answer that question? There is no code, no error logs, no screenshots, no resource info and no even a clue...

Comment: There is no error log, no specific code and no need for screenshot because error is TouchWiz Homescreen crashed. How can I put all my code in here?

Comment: What kind of app are you developing? You said, it may be related with resources but did you tried images with lower resolution and dp? The error must be occurred after some changes you have done. What did you change, try to undo changes step by step, if you are using version control, try running older commits and you can find what is wrong, otherwise, there is no clue.

Comment: It was working flawless on Nexus 5X Api 27. Now i am trying to run it on Samsung j2. Actually I couldnt find how do we provide resources for every android dpi. Maybe I couldnt find a nice documentation of it.

Comment: Just check https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **I have solved the problem**

I have encountered this problem before with Samsung J2. It usually happens because of Layout issues. Try to change your layout.

### **Touchwiz Crash Solution**

Go to Applications and force quit Touchwiz Homescreen